# Selectively apply AWS Headers while uploading static files using django-storages

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I want to selectively apply AWS headers based on my file type and filename pattern while uploading them to S3 origin. I am using django-storages with django 1.8.12

I can see the setting AWS_HEADERS in [django-storages documentation](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html), but I can't seem to find a way to apply this setting on some files only.
I would appreciate if someone can guide me on this

Comment: hello @anurag, did my answer for which flim gave a bounty work out for you as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest is to subclass `storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage` to introduce the required behavior

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class MyS3Storage(S3BotoStorage):

    def _save(self, name, content):
        cleaned_name = self._clean_name(name)
        name = self._normalize_name(cleaned_name)

        _type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(name)
        content_type = getattr(content, 'content_type',
                           _type or self.key_class.DefaultContentType)

        # setting the content_type in the key object is not enough.
        self.headers.update({'Content-Type': content_type})


        if re.match('some pattern', cleaned_name) :
            self.headers.update({'new custome header': 'value'})

        if content_type == 'my/content_type':
            self.headers.update({'new custome header': 'value'})

        return super(MyS3Storage, self)._save(name, content)
```

Don't forget to edit settings and change the file storage definition.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myapp.MyS3Storage'
```

The above code is mainly from the [S3BotoStorage](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/s3boto.py#L397) class with our code merely inspecting the content type and name to add the custom headers.

Comment: sorry @flimm this answer was a rather careless effort. I think i've sorted out all the issues now. Basicially the idea is that you over ride the _save method, which is the place that's best suited for modifying the headers and make the changes as needed. Appologies again about the careless ness

Comment: This works great with one caveat: it won't set a custom `Content-Type` header, because the supermethod will override it.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @Flimm . That caveat can be overcome by copy pasting the rest of the code from _save and editing out that bit, and avoiding the call to the super.

Answer (score 1):

```
#  handlers.py
import mimetypes
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from django.conf import settings

class ManagedS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    def _save(self, name, content):
        cleaned_name = self._clean_name(name)
        _type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(name)
        content_type = getattr(content, 'content_type',
                               _type or self.key_class.DefaultContentType)
        self.headers.update(self.get_headers(cleaned_name, content_type))
        return super(ManagedS3Storage, self)._save(name, content)

     def get_headers(cleaned_name, content_type):
         // if possible, load AWS_HEADERS_LIST from settings
         headers_list = settings.AWS_HEADERS_LIST
         // logic for updating headers & return headers
```

# changes in settings.py file

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'handlers.ManagedS3BotoStorage'
```

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and e4c5's answer? Also, it does not work, `_type` is not defined.

Comment: ooh... was checking the `storage` source for possible solution, forgot to check prev. answer srry

Comment: No worries. :) ````

Comment: @Flimm hope someone will find this usefl, updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are about `S3BotoStorage`, this answer is about `S3Boto3Storage` (notice the `3` after `Boto`). You need to override `_save_content`, like this:

```
class CustomBoto3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    def _save_content(self, obj, content, parameters):
        """We want .mp3 files to have the Content-Disposition header set to
        attachement in this example."""

        new_parameters = parameters.copy() if parameters else {}
        if new_parameters.get('ContentType') in ['audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg-3', 'audio/mpeg']:
            new_parameters['ContentDisposition'] = 'attachment'
        return super()._save_content(obj, content, new_parameters)
```